# metronic portlet expand with external button

Tags: jquery

kennthemes metronic template has portlets that are expandable&collapsable

[http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/portlet_general.html](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/portlet_general.html#)

Portlet has expand button built in menu with following code:

```
<div class="tools">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="expand">
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to control expand function with an external button. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a click handler listening for events from the "expand" and "contract" class. You should be able to call "click" on it if you give it an id or have some other way to get a reference to the element:

```
<div class="tools">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="myCollapse" class="expand">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="others">
    <a href="javascript:$('#myCollapse').click();">
    </a>
</div>
```

I was able to do this in developer tools in Chrome to check that it works. Since you don't actually need to invoke the LINK, using jQuery's `.click()` is enough to invoke the handler.

Answer (score 4):

This is the response I have received from KeenThemes customer support

```
$('#my_portlet .portlet-title .collapse').click();
$('#my_portlet .portlet-title .expand').click();
```